# All possible paths in n*n matrix - python

Tags: python, recursion, matrix

I am trying to solve a interview question:

> Given a n*n matrix, assume you are starting at top-left cell(i.e. 0,0). You are allowed to move either right or down and you have to travel to the bottom right cell. Get the maximum value less than the given value. For example, assume 3*3 matrix, given value is `5`.

```
0 1 2
2 1 2
3 2 1

optimal path is 0 -> 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 = 5
```

I started coding using recursion but the answer is not correct. Any suggestions?

```
def findAllPaths(currX, currY, path, grid, sum):
    #print currX, currY
    if currX == len(grid)-1:
        i = currY
        temp = 0
        while i < len(grid):
            path = path + str(grid[currX][i])
            temp += grid[currX][i]
            i += 1
        sum.append(temp)
        #print 'first loop', sum, path
        return
    if currY == len(grid)-1:
        i = currX
        temp = 0
        while i < len(grid):
            path = path + str(grid[i][currY])
            temp += grid[i][currY]
            i += 1
        sum.append(temp)
        #print 'second loop', sum, path
        return
    #print currX, currY
    #path = path + str(grid[currX][currY])
    findAllPaths(currX+1,currY,path,grid, sum)
    findAllPaths(currX, currY+1,path,grid, sum)

    return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

You're appending to sum and path without ever removing stuff.  This is problematic with a recursive function, as you will try one path, and when you backtrack, you don't remove those.  You either need to make copies (`cpysum = sum[:]`) or remove stuff after you recurse but don't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am using dynamic programming to do the task. by finding the minimum value of the path, the program only need to calculate the current value + the minimum value of last step.

```
def minPathSum(grid):
        res = 0
        if grid:
            n,m = len(grid),len(grid[0])
            dp = [[0]* m for _ in range(n)]
            dp[0][0]= grid[0][0]
            for i in range(1,m):
                dp[0][i] = dp[0][i-1] + grid[0][i]
            for i in range(1,n):
                dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][0]+grid[i][0]

            for i in range(1,n):
                for j in range(1,m):
                    dp[i][j] = grid[i][j]
                    dp[i][j] += min(dp[i][j-1],dp[i-1][j])

            res = dp[-1][-1]
        return res

grid = [ [0,1,2],[2 ,1 ,2],[3 ,2 ,1]]
print(minPathSum(grid))
```